# unable to read file on ntfs

Tags: permissions, ntfs

I have an ubuntu and windows on dualboot. While I'm mainly using ubuntu, I would save all my work in the windows directory, which is an ntfs. The partition is mounted as follows:

```
UUID=ACAEAD7DAEAD4126 /media/windows/ ntfs rw,auto,user,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0   0
```

I have a pdf file that was originally obtained while on Windows which I cannot read in ubuntu (read will return EACCES (Permission denied)). It opens fine in windows.

```
$ cat lab2.pdf 
cat: lab2.pdf: Permission denied
$ sudo cat lab2.pdf
[sudo] password for randy: 
cat: lab2.pdf: Permission denied
$ ls -l lab2.pdf
-rwxrwxr-- 1 randy plugdev 57096 Jan 11  2016 lab2.pdf
```

I've also tried to remount the partition to give full permission:

```
$ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o gid=randy,uid=randy /dev/sda5 /media/windows/
$ ls -l lab2.pdf 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 randy randy 57096 Jan 11  2016 lab2.pdf
$ cat lab2.pdf 
cat: lab2.pdf: Permission denied
```

The weird thing is that I haven't found any other files in the windows directory having the same issue. Would appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: Check if the file has a restrictive access control list. In the WIndows Explorer, that's Properties → Security or something like that. I don't know how to check the ACL from Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions to the specified folders. Try access as root (root console/root account). Permissions can be tideous.
Also check if you protected the partition in Windows